# Android Mediation

Tags: android, admob, millennial-media

I am using the ADMOB for showing Ads in my android app. As the RPM is going down every day, I am planning to tryout some mediation like Millenium Media.

When I searched the document in Admob It again point me to the 3rd part Ad  network site Millenium Media. there the explaination is clear on how to download the SDK and register My App.

I have registered my APP and tested the Millenium Media Ads separately.

### Question:

1. When we use the Admob for mediation service. Why do we need to Import the millennium Media SDK into the APP.
2. When admob displays the Ad from Millenium Media / and 3rd party Ad Network the methods from the ADMOB listeners (onAdLoaded() / onAdLeftApplication() / onAdFailedToLoad() ) will be called ?
3. If we are going to import many 3rd pary SDK the size may grow up. any alternative for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because Admob mediation hands off to an interfae that is implemented by MillennialMedia. That implementation comes from the MillennialMedia SDK.
2. Yes, the AdListener methods will be called.
3. No. But I suggest you mitigate by
   a) Only integrating a couple of networks (you really need no more than 3 good ones). Admob and Millennial are both good IMHO. If you find a third good one let me know. I've tried most and they all have their pain points.
   b) Use Proguard to strip out ad network classes that you don't use.

Comment: Just want to confirm the Answer # 2. You are saying that the Admob's Adlisterner will be called and there is no need for implementation of any method from MillenialMedia As everything is taken care by Admob. We have to just use the Millenialmedia's SDK